# Saving sum of squared deviations results when applied to a large dataset in R

Tags: r, optimization

I'm trying to improve my R code where I want to store the results sum of squared deviations in a specific way.

I have the following dataset:

```
#crate dataset
sample.nr <- c(rep(1,9), rep(2,9))
lot.name <- rep( c("L01", "L02", "L03"),6)
set.seed(23); concentration <- rnorm(18, mean = 135, sd = 1)

dtf<- cbind.data.frame(sample.nr, lot.name, concentration)
str(dtf)
```

Then for each combination of lot.name x sample.nr , want to calculate the sum of squared deviations.

I used the following code to make the calculations and store the results:
lot.id <- unique(lot.name)
sample.id <- unique(sample.nr)

```
#save results
output <- setNames( data.frame( matrix( ncol=length(lot.id), nrow=length(sample.id))),  c("L01", "L02", "L03") )

for (i in 1:length(sample.id)){
  
  for (j in 1:length(lot.id)){
    
      dtA <- dtf[ dtf$lot.name == lot.id[j] &  dtf$sample.nr == sample.id[i], ]   
    
      css <- sum( (dtA[,3] − mean(dtA[,3])) ^2 )
      
      output[i,j] <- css
  }
  
}
```

For a small dataset, the for loops work fine but if I have larger datasets (with thousands of sample.nr and lot.name) it will take a long time to run.

I have tried to use the "aggregate" function but I couldn't the following function:

```
css.func <- function(x) {sum( (x − mean(x)) ^2 )}
```

What is the best approach to make my code faster for large datasets using base R functions?

Answer (score 2):

You can apply `css.func` using `aggregate`.

```
css.func <- function(x) sum( (x - mean(x)) ^2)

res <- aggregate(concentration~sample.nr + lot.name, dtf, css.func)
res

#  sample.nr lot.name concentration
#1         1      L01     2.3578970
#2         2      L01     1.8131202
#3         1      L02     1.3876277
#4         2      L02     0.5393667
#5         1      L03     0.6396029
#6         2      L03     0.3310342
```

Then you may `reshape` the data -

```
reshape(res, idvar = "sample.nr", timevar = "lot.name", direction = "wide")

#  sample.nr concentration.L01 concentration.L02 concentration.L03
#1         1          2.357897         1.3876277         0.6396029
#2         2          1.813120         0.5393667         0.3310342
```

Comment: Thanks. Then I need to "reshape" the output from the aggregate function to have the same format as I have in my output (rows= sample.nr, columns = lot.name; 2x3)

Comment: Updated the answer to reshape the data.